# VLOOKUP for Text Values in Cell

Tags: vlookup

I am trying to compare records in worksheet to records in another worksheet. The only way to match the records is on the text values in the cells, however, the text values are in different orders.

The first column has these values:
Project A (Widget)
Project B (Widget)
Project C (Widget)
Project D (Widget)

The second column has these values:
Widget (Project A)
Widget (Project C)
Widget (Project D)

I tried the following VLOOKUP with no luck:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&$A$1&"*",$C$1:$C$10,1,FALSE)
```

Is there another way I could do this?

Comment: What unexpected result do you see?